# How to create a multiple datasets and set acess in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, terraform, dataset

I need to create multiple datasets and assign a service account to each, giving access with the BigQuery Admin role.

variables.tf

```
variable "project_id" {
  type = string
  default = "<projectid>"
}

variable "set_location" {
  type = string
  default = "southamerica-east1"
}

variable "dataset_name" {
  type = list
  default = ["firs-dataset",
              "second-dataset"]
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "dataset" {
  dataset_id = "${var.dataset_name[count.index]}"
  count = length("${var.dataset_name}")
  location = "${var.set_location}"

  access {
    role = "roles/bigquery.admin"
    user_by_email = "<service-account>"
  }
}
```

With that I can create multiple datasets, but this way I can put permission on just one service account for all datasets.

I need each dataset to have a specific service account with the BigQueryAdmin role.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure `datasets` in a `json` file.

The `Terraform` module structure used in this example is :

```
datasets
  resource/datasets.json
  main.tf
  locals.tf
```

`datasets.json` file :

```json
{
  "datasets": {
    "dataset1": {
      "dataset_id": "dataset1",
      "location" : "EU",
      "friendly_name" : "Name",
      "description" : "Description",
      "role": "roles/bigquery.admin",
      "service_account": "account1@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    },
    "dataset2": {
      "dataset_id": "dataset2",
      "location" : "EU",
      "friendly_name" : "Name",
      "description" : "Description",
      "role": "roles/bigquery.admin",
      "service_account": "account2@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
    }
  }
}
```

You can then retrieve this list in a `locals.tf` file :

```
locals {
  datasets = jsondecode(file("${path.module}/resource/datasets.json"))["datasets"]
}
```

In the `main.tf` file, we loop on the previous `datasets` configured list :

```
resource "google_bigquery_dataset" "datasets" {
  for_each = local.datasets

  project                     = var.project_id
  dataset_id                  = each.value["dataset_id"]
  friendly_name               = each.value["friendly_name"]
  description                 = each.value["description"]
  location                    = each.value["location"]

  access {
    role = each.value["role"]
    user_by_email = each.value["service_account"]
  }
}
```

Comment: and whata bout main.tf how they looks like?

Comment: It was a typo, I added the resource.tf name but it was a mistake, it’s the main.tf file. I updated my answer.

Comment: this works pretty well, now i can only edit json file. Thank you mister!

Comment: @antonio-junior if your problem was solved, please can you mark the answer as solved to help others ?

Comment: Of course my friend, could you help me with this issue of not being able to add more datasets?

Comment: Terraform shows changes everytime in unchanged datasets when you add a new dataset in the list ? Maybe this behaviour occurs in the first time because you migrating the old way to the new with foreach.

Comment: Yes, when I add a new dataset in the .json it adds normally, but it changes all the others already created, removing and subscribing permissions.How can I fix that? I just need to create datasets and not change the already created.
In this print I tried to add two new datasets, this works, but it tries to change everything else. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZE8f.png

Comment: I think you have to migrate your old resource to the new with foreach. The command to use is terraform state mv, example : terraform state mv google_cloud_scheduler_job.job 'google_cloud_scheduler_job.job["desc 2"]' you can check from this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70252615/how-to-keep-terraform-resource-after-refactoring-to-use-for-each

Answer (score 0):

This code works pretty well.
I created all datasets with specific roles.
But now i have a problem, when a try to run another "terraform apply" he tries to change all datasets overrite permissions then already set..

[look the image, when a try to add another dataset, he wants to change everything](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WZE8f.png)

You know a way to fix that?
When a add another dataset in json the others have no changed? because content of json file still the same.

Comment: someone can help?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).